What is the U.S. equivalent of the term "grassroots employees" in the field of management?
The term "grassroots employees" is used in an academic paper to mean employees who are not supervisors, managers, or leaders. This term has only 29,000 google hits. A cursory google search reveals that most published papers using this term are by Chinese authors. What is the U.S. equivalent of this term in the field of management? The term needs to be broad enough to cover all employees who don't have supervisory authority and above. Thank you!

We just say nonsupervisory employees.

Thank you. I'll think I'll go with that

A common term in business is "individual contributor". The Census Blog defines it as:

An individual contributor is someone who contributes to technical projects and performs duties specific to the goals and output of the team. Unlike managers, they do not have any direct reports. Their sole responsibility is to focus on their own skill development and how they contribute to the company as a whole.

(Highlighting comes from the original text.)

This...........

From Ludwig

Frontiers of Business Research in China
Job level: "1" grassroots employee, "2" first-line manager, "3" middle manager.
The Guardian In tech, we face a myriad of issues that need
grassroots, employee-driven movements to effect change.

OED:

Grassroots/grass roots
2.figurative. In plural (frequently in form grassroots).
2.a. Originally U.S. Ordinary people considered as the foundation or main body of an organization, industry, etc., or of society more
generally; esp. ordinary voters or the ordinary members of a political
or social organization, movement, etc.; the rank and file. Sometimes
difficult to distinguish from sense 2b.
1912 From the Roosevelt standpoint, especially, it was a campaign from
the ‘grass roots up’. The voter was the thing. McClure's Magazine
July 324/1
2015 These delegates must represent the grass roots of their parties
as well as other voters if they are going to succeed in the electoral
wars. J. S. Jackson, American Polit. Party Syst. vi. 116
2.b. The origin, source, or foundation of something. Now chiefly (often influenced by sense 2a): the fundamental or most basic level of
an organization, industry, etc., or of society more generally.
2000 Thomas' master plan took him from the grass roots of the data
processing industry..to high-profile CIO positions and finally to the
corner office. Network World 17 July 73/1

As this seems popular in PRC, I suspect it is replacing "the workers" / the working classes / the peasant, etc.

"rank and file" from 2a is a good term for the ordinary employees (although it's originally a military expression).

I considered "rank-and-file employees" but I feel like it has a slight pejorative connotation.

@Ludwig  I'm looking for the U.S. term.

@Eggy - 1. Ludwig is a website... 2. The definition distinctly states that "grassroots" is an American term. -- It is not Chinese-English. - You don't need an alternative.

@ Greybeard The relatively low number of google hits for "grassroots employees" indicates that this is not a common term. With the thousands of publications in business management, I would expect to encounter it more often. I've never heard "grassroots employees" even though I work frequently with publications in this field. As I stated, I only found it used it publications by Chinese authors.

@Eggy Have you considered that the lack of examples reflects only the rarity  of the use of any word of this description? You will wish to give an example sentence so that we can consider the most appropriate word or phrase. You will further note that only one of the examples given is of Chinese origin and I have only taken a few examples.

To answer your question, no, I haven't considered that the lack of examples reflects the rarity of the use of any word for this class of workers, because hundreds of articles are written about relations between leaders/managers/supervisors and these "other" workers. An example sentence? "This study investigated whether religious affiliation impacts opportunities for [this class of workers] to be promoted to managerial positions." As a native speaker of U.S. English I was struck by the term "grassroots employees" because I've never heard it before, despite working on publications in management.
